# how to do Json object Sorting in the node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

```
var data={ '0':
   { 
     benchmark: null,
     hint: '',
     _id: '54fe44dadf0632654a000fbd',
     date: '2015-05-10T01:11:54.479Z' },
  '1':
  { 
     benchmark: null,
     hint: '',
     _id: '54fe44d9df0632654a000fac',
     date: '2015-05-10T01:11:53.608Z' },
  '2':
   { 
     body: '{}',
     benchmark: null,
     _id: '54fe44d8df0632654a000fa4',
     date: '2015-05-10T01:11:52.934Z' }
}

// data sorting
console.info(data);
```

I want to sorting a data by '_id'

how to do it?

Comment: Do you mean sort the data in a variable or sort the data already in the database?

Comment: _id mongodb objectid, this is timestamp.

I want to sort it. in the node.js

Comment: well, you don't appear to have an array here, you have an object which holds a series of other objects.  you will either have to convert to an array of objects and sort the array, or write your own sorting algorithm.

Comment: also, `_id` is not a timestamp, you can use `getTimestamp()` to see when the `_id` was created, but they are not guaranteed to be in sequential order.  from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/ : "•sorting on an _id field that stores ObjectId values is **roughly** equivalent to sorting by creation time"

Comment: well, I just want to sort  by _id. I merge collection's documents. but, It is sorting, i will sort it by '_id'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it in my personal code. You may need to re-write the `=>` functions if you're not using Ecmascript 6 yet.

I didn't provide a comparison function but you could cobble one together using [a, b].sort(); if you wanted maximum concision.

```
var data = { '0':
   {
     benchmark: null,
     hint: '',
     _id: '54fe44dadf0632654a000fbd',
     date: '2015-05-10T01:11:54.479Z' },
  '1':
  {
     benchmark: null,
     hint: '',
     _id: '54fe44d9df0632654a000fac',
     date: '2015-05-10T01:11:53.608Z' },
  '2':
   {
     body: '{}',
     benchmark: null,
     _id: '54fe44d8df0632654a000fa4',
     date: '2015-05-10T01:11:52.934Z' }
}

// use functional chaining to create a sorted out of the data
// 1. Object.keys(data) returns an array of the keys in `data`, ie ['0', '1', '2']
// see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys
const sorted = Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
  // 2. transform each key to be that value instead.
  //    '1' becomes { benchmark: null, ...}, so now we have an array of values
  //    the end result of map() is  [ { benchmark: null, ... }, ... ]
  //    see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
  return data[key];
}, []).sort((a, b) => {
  // 3. sort the resulting values array using Array.prototype.sort, which allows
  //    you to provide your own comparison callback to determine order.
  return compare(a._id,  b._id);
})

function compare(a, b) {
  // your string ordering code here.
  // feel free to use Array.sort() here to do unicode codepoint order sort.
  // see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
}
```

Comment: ```
const sorted = Object.keys(data).reduce((accum, key) => {
  accum.push(data[key]);
  return accum;
}, []).sort((a, b) => {
  return compare(a._id,  b._id);
})
```

I don't understand this code.
```

Comment: @Seung updated it to be a bit more readable, and added inline comments.